# Delete route not found in node.js/express

Tags: node.js, express

Not the first time I'm doing it but for some reason one of the delete routes in my node.js/express app is not working:

app.js:

```
var model = require('./server/model/system')(config);
app.use('/api/systems', require('./server/api/system')(model));
```

/server/api/system.js (not called)

```
router.delete('/:id', function _delete(req, res) {
        .
        .
        .
    });
```

jade file (breakpoint is hit with correct systemId):

```
system.$delete({id:systemId}, function(){
            .
            .
            .
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: have you tried some console inside the route ?

Comment: Yes but nothing (also with breakpoints). The code is not reached.